# Android Building a News app which loads many images e.g Pulse, Google Currents

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-image, pulse

I am working on a news app, which fetches lots of news articles with images, much like Pulse and Google currents -> many categories containing very many news articles with images. How can I achieve this without running into Out of Memory errors.

Comment: post your code and logcat for better understanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) explains pretty well how to deal with this issue.